# Como puedo dividir un txt despues de 100 caracteres generados en c++

Tags: c++, txt

tengo un archivo que cree en c++ con la libreria fstream y necesito que despues de 100 caracteres me genere otro archivo ejemplo ejemplo1.txt, ejemplo2.txt, ejemplo3.txt etc me podrian ambientarme como lo puedo hacer muchas gracias.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

ofstream limitar("ejemplo.txt");

limitar << "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum." ;

return 0; }
```

Comment: Cuentas cuantos caracteres llevas escritos, y cuando llegas a 100 creas un archivo nuevo?

Comment: si señor por eejmplo en el archvo lorem tengo un parrafo necesito que cada 100 o 50 palabras de ese parafo me cree el archivo consecutivo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar los iteradores de flujo de datos:

```
if (std::ifstream entrada{"archivo.txt"})
{
    for (int indice = 0; entrada; ++indice)
    {
        std::string archivo{"archivo_A.txt"};
        archivo[8] += indice;

        if (std::ofstream salida{archivo})
        {
            std::cout << "Escribiendo " << archivo << '\n';
            /* Copiar 100 elementos de tipo char desde el archivo de entrada
            al archivo de salida */
            std::copy_n
            (
                std::istream_iterator<char>{entrada},
                100,
                std::ostream_iterator<char>{salida}
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Usando `std::copy_n` consigues copiar exáctamente 100 elementos en cada llamada, pero si la cantidad de datos de entrada no es múltiplo de cien, el último archivo tendrá caracteres incorrectos al final (puedes verlo en [este ejemplo](https://tio.run/##lVPLTsMwEDzbX2GFA61CUUBCQm1aiQNHvoCiyjhOu1JqV45bgar8OmHtOG36oMAhknc93p3Z2YjVaiAKruZ1fQVKFOtMshR0aY3kywnd5/LTFFhpuNWmm@PFXBuwiwMgPgU1n1C60ZAxgXXMjBuxgI3u9emWEshZr7TZcKhDGxaut1E43NoPG1V9ShBNcm1YD5RloDIQko1ZMmrPKXtIMIrjJsYXhIQaLE0DakRJRStK37Uu2NKp7TDaF/bcPK9GwQmr2VPDC@uFzOvjG4vHuzYdadBKs7K02wBvFXmE0GvrOEYvnpHKNJMFE1pZqQCDDKNWSuSAHV3RcKqi0b7S6jN0bZrOWq9SseBmsnUcqht2CdJe6/PXO8ZV30@TyKKU2N9IuzaK5RxDpz/E1qwxxJG76S45qMb4o104PzCpcBoZ/8cuhBeHa@DQf3WT/OgnObOsJS8A@XU8Dd2OfH0uhYF3kM7ZYwOvp@p61H2z@pypix4GkejTXZL8YpYn6J0iziv3oRfnh3f6P/gJHg7zUNhU@e3buZ2g1XX9JfKCz8t6gOCxiON7/g0)), si quieres evitar eso no uses esa función:

```
if (std::ifstream entrada{"archivo.txt"})
{
    for (int indice = 0; entrada; ++indice)
    {
        std::string archivo{"archivo_A.txt"};
        archivo[8] += indice;

        if (std::ofstream salida{archivo})
        {
            std::cout << "Escribiendo " << archivo << '\n';
            int n = 0;
            for (std::istream_iterator<char> begin{entrada}, end{}; begin != end; ++begin)
            {
                if (n++ < 100)
                    salida << *begin;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVPbjtMwEH22v8KEh20JiwrSSqs2rcQDj3wBRZXrOOmI1K4cdwWK8uuE8cRp0wsreIk893PmTNTh8KgqacquewtGVcdciwxs7Z2W@xU/@4pbF3jtpLdu7JNVaR343UUiloIpV5y/WMiFwj5uI53awYudTHnDGRRiUvt8PrdxjIjhJomPD/6nT9opZ5jNCuvEBIwXYHJQWizFbDG8M/E0QytNexsrGIs9RJbFrAVnLW8531pbiX1gO0J0bkzYCFfP4AbV5nOPC/tFz7fn7yJdnsaMqMFAzevaNzF9YEQZyh59wJh8JUQmt0JXQlnjtQE0crQGKklIHPFK5muTLM6dDr/i1H7oZtAqUzvpVk3A0L4Xr6UMYXs/fELcTmmbTFe1xvlO@6MzopBoBv7R9u6IJq48bHcvwfTCX93C/YVpg9vI5X/cQqy4PIOQ/a9qsr/qye4cay0rQHwjTeO0K12/1MrBFnRQ9lrAh7V5oMEskDHEg0wi@IpQYqtLME2kjKph@6bnwBjFxJtlcIZtkE34IkBiY9IU/5uPs1kfQdhEKMB6RxWxW5SYGiOSH7275fHThjvg9xW5/clIlkuFLre1NnTSpxPCfbRd91sVlSzr7hGTlypNP8k/)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchas agracias me ha servido mucho tu orientacion